# Including jquery in existing jquery code and scoping a variable as global

Tags: javascript, jquery

I called an external javascript using this but not able to send a variable to the included file to use it there accordingly.

```
    var Evaluator = 11;

    var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = '/evaluate.js';
        script.type = 'text/javascript';

        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Now in `evaluate.js` , when I `alert(Evaluator);`, it yields **undefined**.....what to do?

This whole jquery code is written and sent via ajax to a separate file from which the result is loaded into the main file and displayed , the result loads when user clicks on a button.

Comment: whether this code is within a function

Comment: @ArunPJohny : yes , its within a function : load()

Comment: that is the problem... then `Evaluator` is not a global variable... try `window.Evaluator = 1`

Comment: so Evaluator can't be used in the included file -evaluate.js? I want to use it in evaluate.js and work accordingly.

Comment: *"so Evaluator can't be used in the included file -evaluate.js?"* Not as it is defined here, but if you make it a global variable, then yes.

Comment: fine, so I need to do window.Evaluator = 11 , then it would work i guess ?

Comment: @sqlchild yes it would

Comment: The `Evaluator` is declared in a local scope in your case... so it will be only accessible within that method... if you want to use it another function then you need to declare it in a scope shared between both the methods...

Comment: @ArunPJohny : what would be that scope then? how do i use it.....oh , its the 'window.Evaluator' ,  isn't it? what would be the life of this variable then and will it be accessible in all my files on my website

Comment: @sqlchild yes it will be...

Comment: @ArunPJohny : but it will then override the other uses of Evaluator variable in other files js codes...I need it for only the included js file that's it and not for all my files on my website

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43511/discussion-between-sqlchild-and-arun-p-johny)